# Hortonworks Data node install: Exception in secureMain

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

Am trying to install Hortonworks Hadoop single node cluster. I am able to start namenode and secondary namenode, but datanode failed with the following error. How do I solve this issue?

> 2014-04-04 18:22:49,975 FATAL datanode.DataNode (DataNode.java:secureMain(1841)) - Exception in secureMain
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Although a UNIX domain socket path is configured as /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket, we cannot start a localDataXceiverServer because libhadoop cannot be loaded."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Native Libraries Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html#Native_Hadoop_Library). Make sure libhadoop.so is available in $HADOOP_HOME\bin. Look into the logs for this message:

```
INFO util.NativeCodeLoader - Loaded the native-hadoop library
```

If instead you find

```
INFO util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

then it means the libhadoop.so is not available, and you'll have to investigate why. Alternatively you can turn off [HDFS shortcircuit](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ShortCircuitLocalReads.html) if you wish, or enable the legacy short-circuit instead using `dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader.local`, to remove the libhadoop dependency. But I reckon would be better to find out what's the problem with your library.

Make sure you read and understand the articles linked before asking further questions.

Comment: I find the  `libhadoop.so` in `HADOOP_HOME/lib/native` but not `HADOOP_HOME/bin`. Is that not good?